# Can you check if it's a group monomorphism from the group presentations?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory, monomorphisms

Let $G_{1}$, $G_{2}$ be two groups given by their presentations. Then if $f$ is a map defined on the generators of $G_{1}$ we can prove that $f$ is a homomorphism by proving that the set of the relations of $G_{1}$ is mapped through $f$ to relations that hold in $G_{2}$. Is there a similar way to prove that $f$ is 1-1 by using the fact that we know the presentation of both groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Showing that $f$ is 1-1 would amount to showing that for distinct $a$ and $b$ in $G_1$ that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are distinct in $G_2$. In general this is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) given just the presentation of $G_2$. See [The word problem for groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups).

Comment: By similar reasoning, isn't the OP's approach to proving $f$ is a homomorphism also undecidable?  (Since it amounts to checking if $f(r)$ is equivalent to the identity element for each relation $r$ in the presentation for $G_1$).  Is there, then, some general procedure the OP can follow follow (in the spirit of his/her undecidable approach to checking if $f$ is a homomorphism) which determines if $f$ is injective?

Comment: @Jason The procedure of the OPs is really a "half algorithm" - if a word is equal to the identity then we can verify this, by writing it as a product of conjugates of realtors (the issue is knowing when to stop trying to write it this way and conclude that it is non-trivial). So we can always *verify* if a map is a homomorphism. However, by using the same half-procedure on elements of the image of our map, we see that we can always verify if a map is *not* injective. So, in a certain sense, the answer to your question is "no", because the relevant half-algorithm verifies the wrong thing...

Comment: @user1729:  Would it be fair to reformulate what you said as follows?  Given a function $f$ between finite presentations for groups $G_1$ and $G_2$, there is a computer program which halts iff $f$ is a homomorphism, but there is no program halts if and only if $f$ is not a function.  Similarly,  there is a computer program which halts iff $f$ is *not* injective, but there is no computer program halts iff $f$ is injective.

Comment: @Jason Yes, except the word "function" should be replaced with "homomorphism".

Comment: @user1729:  Thanks for clarifying!